# Loading data into an app from external website?

Tags: android, parsing, android-asynctask, android-webview, local-storage

I am wondering what possible ways would be for loading a simple website into my app. My first thought is using a WebView, but I would like a dynamic app, while webview takes some time when loading between pages and links.

Is a common solution to load the html resources locally, from let say the assets folder? Than I could use AsyncTask to keep the files up to date and whenever the app starts it would load and work much quickly.

Or should I use HTTP Requests and parse the external Html document?

What would be the most situable solution for this kind of app?

Thanks,
Ved

Answer (score 0):

I belive you should think about the data you need to build that html. If you'r app use a simple static data I recommned you to save the html and the data refered to html in assets folder, cause you will not have a server HTTP request to load.
In the same way I will put the html page at assets folder if html is dinamically created with static data.
Only if the data to build that html is dinamically changed and can't be covered with updates,
I'll use HTTP request to server.

Finally, if you think that you'r app needs a lot of html code I belive the better options is to create a phongap app.